# Proving that Ring of Complex Entire functions is neither Artinian nor Noetherian

Tags: analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

**Question:** Prove that the Ring of Complex Entire functions is neither Artinian nor noetherian.

Proof: Clearly $R$ is not Artinian because it is a commutative integral domain which is not a field, and $R$ is not noetherian because it is  not  a factorisation domain.

Is there a proof of this theorem using the Ascending / Descending Chain condition for Artinian / Noetherian rings?

Comment: Reéated: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1378133

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $J_n$ be the ideal of entire functions vanishing on the first $n$ positive integers, and let $I_n$ be the ideal of entire functions vanishing on positive integers greater than $n$.  Then $$J_1\supset J_2\supset J_3\supset\cdots,$$ $$I_1\subset I_2\subset I_3\subset\cdots,$$ and all of these containments are proper.  One way to see that the containments are proper is to use the fact that given any sequence of complex numbers $a_1,a_2,\ldots$, there is an entire function $f$ such that $f(n)=a_n$ for each positive integer $n$.  For more on this, see [these](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20711/does-there-exist-a-holomorphic-function-which-takes-given-values-on-the-positive) [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2944/) [questions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7328/interpolation-of-sequences-by-analytic-functions).

Comment: I feel compelled to add that that result I mentioned is overkill for this.  To see that the containments of the $J_k$s are proper you could use the polynomials $(z-1)(z-2)\cdots(z-k)$.  To see that the containments of the $I_k$s are proper you could divide $\sin(\pi x)$ by those polynomials.

Comment: To prove the strict inclusions of the $I_n$, wouldn't it be sufficient to argue that there exists an entire function whose only zeros, counted with their multiplicities are $n,n+1,\dots$? This result is a simple application of Weierstrass factorisation theorem, c.f. Walter Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, 3rd ed., theorem 15.11.

Comment: @Akerbeltz: Existence of $\sin(\pi x)$ mentioned in my comment is even simpler, but my original justification was overkill definitely.