# Neither Artinian nor Noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I read a message about the ring of complex entire functions, that is neither Artinian nor Noetherian (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/proving-that-ring-of-complex-entire-functions-is-neither-artinian-nor-noetherian)).

> Can you show me other examples of rings that are neither Artinian nor Noetherian?

Comment: [DaRT query](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&L=64l) for non-Noetherian (necessarily non-Artinian) commutative rings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For commutative rings (**edit:** I required commutative rings to have a $1$), the condition that $R$ is Artinian is equivalent to the condition that $R$ is Noetherian and has Krull dimension $0$. Thus any commutative ring which is not Noetherian is not Artinian either. One common example is the ring $A$ of algebraic integers. It has an infinite ascending chain of ideals as follows:
$$(2)\subset (\sqrt{2})\subset (\sqrt[3]{2})\subset\cdots$$
and an infinite descending chain of ideals:
$$(2)\supset (2^2)\supset(2^3)\supset\cdots$$
Another example is the ring $R$ of polynomials over the field $k$ in infinitely many variables, which has an infinite ascending chain of ideals:
$$(x_1)\subset(x_1,x_2)\subset(x_1,x_2,x_3)\subset\cdots$$
and an infinite descending chain chain of ideals:
$$(x_1)\supset(x_1^2)\supset(x_1^3)\supset\cdots$$
Note that these are just examples of infinite ascending and descending chains of ideals in these rings; many more exist.

Comment: I think you've got your inclusions the wrong way round in your second and fourth chains

Comment: @DanielFreedman Yes, thanks.

Comment: I don't think the inclusions in your first chain work as stated - the roots need to be 1st, 2nd, 4th, 8th etc

Comment: @MarkBennet $\sqrt{2}=\sqrt[6]{2}\sqrt[3]{2}$ and $\sqrt[6]{2}\in A$.

Comment: @AlexBecker - thanks, brain on hold

Comment: @MarkBennet No problem. I often mess up, so I'm glad people double-check me.

Comment: @AlexBecker: it is not true that any commutative ring which is not Noetherian is not Artinian either; there are additive groups $G$ for which you define $a \cdot b$ as  $0$ for all $a,b \in G$  that are not Noetherian, but they are Artinian.

Comment: @Oo3 I require unity in my definition of commutative ring. I'll edit to make that clear.

Answer (score 7):

For any field $k$ consider the ring of polynomials in infnite many variables $k[\{x_n:n\in \mathbb N\}]$. It is not noetherian and hence is not artinian.