# ideal of holomorphic function that vanish on all but finite number of integers is not finite generated

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be the ring of holomorphic function on $\Bbb{C}^1$. I want to show that the ideal of functions that vanish on all but a finite number of integers is not finitely generated, therefore the ring above is non-Noetherian.

---

My attempt if it's generated by $f_1,...,f_n$, my feeling is that I need to use something like the identity principle in some place, sorry I don't have idea.

Comment: I believe this is done in Berenstein & Gay's Complex Variables in Chapter 3.

Comment: thank you mathematics2x2life , I will have a look at it.

Comment: any finitely generated ideal in $\mathcal{O}$ is principal (not hard to prove by induction using Weierstrass theorem about the existence of functions that vanish at precisely given discrete set and some manipulations with $\bar \partial$

Comment: thank you Conrad , I will write down the detail later.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4049/42969

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $I$ denote that ideal and say $f_1, \ldots, f_n$ generate $I$. Note that by definition, there exists an integer $N$ large enough such that each $f_i$ vanishes on $N$. But then every function in $I$ must vanish on $N$. However, you can cook up a function which vanishes on $\Bbb Z$ and not on $N$, which would finish the job.

Comment: Nice answer!  Can we recommend $\frac{\sin \pi z}{z-N}$ for the example?

Comment: Nice answer and nice comment thank you !

Comment: @orangeskid: That's exactly what I had in mind! :)